# How to get newly created elements on top

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, element

So I'm working on a personal project which is just a simple status update. I'm constantly adding more functionality to it but I've been stuck for quite some time now. The problem is that whenever someone posts a new status I want that to appear on top, however the one on top is the first post created, which is a problem. This would mean you'd have to scroll down to the bottom to see the most recent post.

Screenshots:

[Main page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1M0xn.png)

[Problem occurs, new element goes underneath old](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ge9m8.png)

Here is the javascript:

```
function statusPost() {
    status = document.getElementById("Status").value;

    if (status == "") {
        alert("Please write a status")
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("Status").value = "";
        div = document.createElement("div");
        document.getElementById("container").appendChild(div);
        div.className = "update";
        div.innerHTML = status;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is indeed, thanks for the link :p Fixed the issue now!

Answer (score 2):

instead of appending `div` at the end of `container`, you should `prepend` it using `insertBefore`

here is your modified code (I saved some references to elements to maintain readability)

```
var status = document.getElementById("Status");
var container = document.getElementById("container");

function statusPost() {
    if (status.value == "") {
        alert("Please write a status")
    } else {
        status.value = "";
        div = document.createElement("div");
        div.className = "update";
        div.innerHTML = status;
        container.insertBefore(div, container.firstChild);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use insertBefore() instead of appendChild()

Check it out here:

[W3school link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertbefore.asp)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery you can use , prepend() method to achieve this. 
The data will come at top.
[Preppend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

```
 <h2>Greetings</h2>
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">Hello</div>
</div>
$( ".inner" ).prepend( "<p>Test</p>" );
```

If you need this in Java Script Please try

```
insertBefore
```